# Split when character changes in Python

Tags: python, string, parsing

So I have this string.

```
6#666#665533999
```

And I want to parse it into multiple small strings(or until the character changes) and ignoring the `#` so that I can substitute `6 = M or 666 = O or 9 = W` just like a phone's dial pad.

```
6#666#665533999 -> 6, 666, 66, 55, 33, 999
```

So I used the `split('#')` method to remove the `#` and can't figure out what to do next.I have tried brute force methods which solves it to a certain extent but is there an easier or more elegant solution to this?

Comment: So would `6#666#665533999` turn into `MONKEY`?

Comment: Also, how would you like to handle Q and Z? Different phones handle them differently

Comment: @inspectorG4dget `Q` will be `77` and `Z` will be `9999`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> c = "6#666#665533999"
>>> ["".join(g) for k, g in groupby(c) if k != '#']
['6', '666', '66', '55', '33', '999']
```

Then have a dictionary which maps each of these sets to a character in the dial pad.

```
cmap = {'77': 'Q', '9999': 'Z'} # And so forth..
```

Answer (score 4):

This is basically the same logic, just wrapped up a bit more tidily:

```
from itertools import groupby

phone_chars = {
    "2": " ABC",
    "3": " DEF",
    "4": " GHI",
    "5": " JKL",
    "6": " MNO",
    "7": " PQRS",
    "8": " TUV",
    "9": " WXYZ",
    "#": ["", ""]
}

def decode(digit_str):
    return "".join(phone_chars[ch][len(list(it))] for ch,it in groupby(digit_str))
```

then

```
>>> print(decode("6#666#665533999"))
MONKEY
```

---

**Edit:**

Python has very good [online documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

`itertools.groupby` accepts an input sequence and an optional `key` parameter which is an evaluation function - it accepts a value, does something to it, and returns the result. If the key function is not given, it defaults to identity (ie `key = lambda x: x`, take a value and return the same value).

It then applies this evaluation function to each item in the input sequence and returns a sequence of `(evaluated_value, iter(consecutive_items_having_the_same_evaluated_value))`.

So

```
groupby("AABBBCCCDD")
```

gets you

```
iter((
    ("A", iter(("A", "A"))),
    ("B", iter(("B", "B", "B"))),
    ("C", iter(("C", "C", "C"))),
    ("D", iter(("D", "D")))
))
```

or (demonstrating a custom evaluation function)

```
groupby([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], key=lambda x: x//3)
```

gives

```
iter((
    (0, iter([1, 2])),      # 1//3 == 2//3 == 0
    (1, iter([3, 4, 5])),   # 3//3 == 4//3 == 5//3 == 1
    (2, iter([6, 7]))       # 6//3 == 7//3 == 2
))
```

Note that iterators only give you one value at a time, and `len` won't work on one because there is no way to know how many values the iterator might return. If you need to count the returned values, the simplest way is `len(list(iterable))` - grab all returned values into a list and then see how many items the list has. So if we do

```
[(ch, len(list(it))) for ch,it in groupby("6#666#665533999")]
```

what we get back is

```
[
    ('6', 1),   # => 'M'
    ('#', 1),   # => ''
    ('6', 3),   # => 'O'
    ('#', 1),   # => ''
    ('6', 2),   # => 'N'
    ('5', 2),   # => 'K'
    ('3', 2),   # => 'E'
    ('9', 3)    # => 'Y'
]
```

which (by design) happens to be exactly the required index values into `phone_chars`. We use the index values to get the corresponding characters - ie `phone_chars['6'][1] == 'M'` - join them together using `"".join()`, and return the resulting string (`"MONKEY"`).

Comment: I was just searching what the above solution is actually doing but still can't wrap my hear around it.Just started python this week and was doing this as a practice exercise.I would really love an explanation about what is actually happening here if I may.

Answer (score 3):

```
def encode(nums):
    return ["".join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(nums) if k != '#']


chars = {str(n):dict(enumerate(chrs,1)) for n,chrs in enumerate("ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQRS TUV WXYZ".split(), 2)}

nums = "6#666#665533999"
nums = encode(nums)
message = ''.join(chars[n[0]][len(n)] for n in nums)

In [28]: message
Out[28]: 'MONKEY'
```