# How to count the number of blocks of contiguous recurring ones/zeros in a binary string in Python

Tags: python, string, binary

So for example, I want the code to return '5' for the input '01000110', since the blocks of recurring digits are '0', '1', '000', '11', '0'. I can't come up with a way to tackle this problem. All help/comments are appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255222/split-when-character-changes-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use regular expressions.

[`(0+|1+)`](https://regex101.com/r/bx52Av/1) will match any continuous regions are 1 or 0, and then you can check the length of the resulting array.

```
import re

s = '01000110' 
print(len(re.findall(r'(0+|1+)', s)))    # ['0', '1', '000', '11', '0']
```

Output:

```
5
```

As @John Coleman pointed out, you could also use itertools, which would be marginally faster on large binary strings:

```
len(list(itertools.groupby(s)))
```

Timings:

```
In [18]: x = np.random.randint(2, size=100000)

In [19]: x = ''.join(map(str, x))

In [20]: %timeit len(re.findall(r'(0+|1+)', x))
10.9 ms ± 327 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [21]: %timeit len(list(itertools.groupby(x)))
9.42 ms ± 173 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [22]: %timeit sum(1 for i in itertools.groupby(x))
9.12 ms ± 156 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I'm surprised that the times are so close. If anything, I would have predicted that the regular expression approach was quicker since you can't directly apply len() to groupby objects. +1 for an interesting comparison.

Comment: @JohnColeman your approach could be made (very) slightly faster by not creating a list, so something like `sum(1 for i in itertools.groupby(x))`, which would consume the generator, but since only the final output is required, would work.

Answer (score 2):

The function `groupby`in the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html) module provides for a natural solution:

```
>>> len(list(itertools.groupby('01000110')))
5
```

As @chrisz points outs, you could make this marginally faster by replacing `len(list())` by `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

given a list of 0s and 1s with length l

```
array = numpy.random.randint(0, 2, (l))
```

the number of consecutive regions are given by this code (not optimized, just to show the concept)

```
count = 1
current_digit = array[0]
for digit in array:
    if digit != current_digit:
        count += 1
        current_digit = digit
count
```

example, with

```
array = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

the number of regions is

```
count = 9
```

Comment: This seems like a natural solution (+1) and shows how to do it without importing modules. I'm not sure why it got a downvote.

Comment: Don't know either, he didn't know how to tackle the problem, so this seemed the most intuitive and conceptually easy way to go